# Soundcloud-api-v2 (crawling data of playlists using user_id)

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I've tried to crawl playlists of user_id = 12 on soundcloud.com using
url = f"https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/12/playlists?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&limit=100"
user_id = 12 has 11 playlists, but I change "limit" to 12 and the result will be 0; if I change "limit" to 100, the result will be 2. And I can't understand how the "limit" work.
May anybody help me to solve this problem? Thank you <3

````r
url_get_all_playlist_of_user = f"https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/12/playlists?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&limit=100"
crawling = r.get(url_get_all_playlist_of_user)
while crawling.ok == False:
    crawling = r.get(url_get_all_playlist_of_user)
json_str = json.loads(crawling.text)
collection = json_str['collection']```
````